# Missiong Permissions error in logs discord.js

Tags: discord.js

So I was updating my addrole command to my bot. I keep getting the error Missing Permissions. The ROle Switch Beta has all Permissions Enabled. The Hihest ROle Bots also has all Permissions enabled.

```
    run: async (bot, message, args) => {

    if(!message.member.hasPermission(["MANAGE_ROLES", "ADMINISTRATOR"])) return message.channel.send(":x: You dont have permission to perform this command!")

    let rMember = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.find(m => m.user.tag === args[0]) || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])
    if(!rMember) return message.channel.send(":x: Please provide a user to add a role too.")
    let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name == args[1]) || message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.id == args[1]) || message.mentions.roles.first()
    if(!role) return message.channel.send(":x: Please provide a role to add to said user.")
    let reason = args.slice(2).join(" ")
    if(!reason) return message.channel.send(":x: Please provide a reason")

    if(!message.guild.me.hasPermission(["MANAGE_ROLES", "ADMINISTRATOR"])) return message.channel.send(":x: I don't have permission to perform this command.")

    if(rMember.roles.cache.has(role.id)) {
        return message.channel.send(`${rMember.displayName}, already has the role!`)
    } else {
        await rMember.roles.add(role.id).catch(e => console.log(e.message))
        message.channel.send(`:white_check_mark: The role, ${role.name}, has been added to ${rMember.displayName}.`)
    }
    }
}
```

I dont know if the permissions changed in discord.js V12 but the whole command works but it is "Missing Permissions"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention anything about your bot's role being higher than the role you want to give. So maybe check that.

Comment: Oh yea! I forgot that if a bots role is lower than the desired role then you cant give roles!